# Question about Rotational Kinematics in David Tong's Notes

Tags: vectors, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics

In the $2$nd page [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics/three.pdf) of David Tong's notes on the Motion of Rigid Bodies, at the bottom there is a claim about the unique existence of a certain time-dependent orthonormal matrix $R(t)$ whose $9$ scalar components $R_{ab}(t)$ (where $a,b\in\{1,2,3\}$) are postulated to be capable of relating the *fixed space frame* basis vectors $\tilde{\textbf e}_a$ (where $a=1,2,3$) to the *moving body frame* basis vectors $\textbf e_a(t)$ (where $a=1,2,3$) via a simple scalar proportionality relation:
$$\textbf e_a(t)=R_{ab}(t)\tilde{\textbf e}_b\space\space \text{ for all}\space a,b\in\{1,2,3\}$$
But this does not seem possible because it is suggesting that each of the moving body frame basis vectors $\textbf e_a(t)$ must be aligned/collinear with each of the fixed space frame basis vectors $\tilde{\textbf e}_a$, hence all of the vectors are collinear! What is the issue in my understanding here?

Comment: Why would it need to be colinear? There is no such restriction here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $R_{ab}$ consists of three columns, each being the unit direction vector (basis vector) of the body frame expressed in the space frame.

$$ R = \begin{Bmatrix} \mathbf{e}_1 & \mathbf{e}_2 & \mathbf{e}_3 \end{Bmatrix} $$

So a vector on the body frame, $\overline{p}' = \pmatrix{x \\ y \\z}$ just described the "distances" along the unit directions.

So the same vector in the space frame has coordinates $\overline{p} = x\, \mathbf{e}_1 + y\, \mathbf{e}_2 + z\, \mathbf{e}_3$ or as a linear algebra operation $$ \overline{p} = R\,\, \overline{p}' $$

The only constraint for the above is that each column is a unit vector, and the columns are mutually exclusive, such at $\mathbf{e}_a \cdot \mathbf{e}_b = 0$ for $a \neq b$, and $\mathbf{e}_a \cdot \mathbf{e}_b = 1$ for $a = b$.

Also since the unit directions change with time (as the body orientation gets "updated") the columns of $R$ are changing with time.

Comment: So what exactly is the difference between the notation $R$ and $R_{ab}$? I would think that $R$ represents the $3\times 3$ matrix itself wheras $R_{ab}$ is being used to denote its $9$ scalar components, i.e.
$$R=\begin{pmatrix}
R_{11} & R_{12} & R_{13} \\
R_{21} & R_{22} & R_{23} \\
R_{31} & R_{32} & R_{33}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Exactly, you got it. If you stick with tensor notation then everything has a subscript, otherwise, you do things with vectors/matrices following linear algebra rules.

Comment: Sorry, I am still confused, because if that is the case (that $R_{ab}(t)$ is a scalar-valued function of time $t$), then the relation $\textbf e_a(t)=R_{ab}(t)\tilde{\textbf e}_b$ would suggest that $\textbf e_a(t)$ and $\tilde{\textbf e}_b$ are always scalar multiples of each other, which suggests collinearity?

Comment: @SurfaceIntegral - you are missing the implicit summation rule $e_{a} = \sum_b R_{a b} e_b$. So it is not scalar relation. BTW this is why I prefer linear algebra to tensor algebra.

Comment: omg, that makes so much sense now, thank you! I didn't realize that there was an implied summation occurring :(

Answer (score 0):

The two frames are not the same. Firstly, $R$ is a $3$x$3$ matrix, not a constant. Secondly, $R$ can depend on time, which introduces time dependence into the moving body frame basis vectors.

Comment: I understand that $R(t)\in\text{SO}(3)$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, but its $9$ $\textit{components}\space R_{ab}(t)$ should be scalars, no?

Comment: So $e_a=R_{ab}\tilde{e}_b$ is three different equations (one for each $a$), with $b$ implicitly summed over. For example, for $a=1$, $$e_1=R_{11}\tilde{e}_1+R_{12}\tilde{e}_2+R_{13}\tilde{e}_3$$ This shows how each $e$ basis vector mixes together different $\tilde{e}$ basis vectors.